# POST/REDIRECT/GET vs custom implementation

Tags: php, forms

I have some forms, and am currently using an implementation as described below:

```
<form action="/formpost.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="to" id="to" value="__COMMENT1" />
    <!-- rest of form -->
</form>
```

`__COMMENT1` refers to the page where I want the user to be redirected after the form posts.

Pretty much what happens is that the form is posted to `formpost.php`, the `$_POST` array is converted to `$_SESSION['POST']`, the `$_POST` is unset, and then the user is redirected to the location referenced in the value of the hidden input field ([id = `to`] always the same ID/name.) I can then continue to use the user's form submitted values (referenced from the `$_SESSION` array) regardless of whether they go 'back', refresh, etc.

Is there anything wrong with this?
Are there any benefits to using the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern instead?

Comment: on what page do you show form validation errors?

Comment: The page I'm redirecting to. (`__COMMENT1`)

Comment: so, you're loading the same form there. I don't see much sense in this. I think it's better to have a form just in one location. and redirect only after successful submit.

Comment: It depends. The user can be redirected to the form on success (with a prominent success message,) or they can be redirected to a plain success page. Depends on the form -- and the client's desires.

Comment: i am talking of error page, not success page

Comment: Oh, error page is the form page. Though, there is no validation per se in the `formpost.php` file. It'd be on whatever the redirect page is -- more than likely the form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your method, it's more convenient than PRG.
though, I see no point in keeping POST variables unless in case of error.
and there is no point in unsetting $_POST, of course.

Well, after some explanation it seems that your setup is quite wrong.
there is no point in making single action for all forms as well as in unnecessary redirect.

make your form action the actual script that validates the form.

- on success, redirect wherever you want.
- on error:

  - save POST data and error messages into session and redirect to the same URL
  - populate the form and unset POST data and errors
  - show the form